# The module has not been deployed, see server log for details

Tags: java, netbeans, glassfish, ejb, javabeans

I have an ejb project and when I run it I'm given an error saying the module has not been deployed see server log for details. I have attached some of the server log below in pastebin.

http://pastebin.com/Xtn4ifa4

It seems that shop_pm is an invalid resource but I don't know how to change that.

Comment: ...you have an invalid resource : Shop__pm....

Comment: @nablex how would I go about making it a valid resource again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define or redefine the jdbc resource "Shop__pm".

I'm thinking it's a typo, perhaps single underscore? "Shop_pm"?